# Is it possible to create a virtualenv without a distribution based Python package installed?

Tags: python, pipenv, python-poetry, pyenv, pyproject.toml

On a blank system (e.g. a bare Debian/Alpine/etc. container) with `pyenv` installed and a `Pipfile`/`pyproject.toml`/.. containing a required version of Python I'd like to create a virtualenv, which is no problem if `pipenv` or `python-pip` are installed already.

But in order to have `pipenv` or `poetry` (or any other similar tool) available, a whole bunch of other packages has to be available in the first place (next to a version of Python I don't need anymore afterwards).

In order to have a slim development image I'm currently thinking of ways to have only the tools available `pyenv` needs to create the version of Python referenced in my `Pipfile`/`pyproject.toml`, which I could then use to actually create an virtualenv from.

The easiest way would be to have `pyenv` itself bootstrap this process, but it can't - can it?

Manual approaches I can think of would either delete the prior installation of Python, or create a multi stage Dockerfile which uses the first stage to provide all packages `pyenv` needs, a second stage which installs a stock Python package together with all packages needed to build the required Python build chain based on a `pyenv`-generated Python. But that sounds complicated.

So since I guess I'm not the first one to be in this situation: Is there a recommended way to create a virtualenv from scratch, with implicit installation of the required version of Python without having to have Python + `pipenv` available in the first place?

Comment: I wouldn't use pipenv with Docker, although it's technically possible to do that.  Why not just use the copy of Python bundled with the base distribution?

Comment: I.e. virtualenv, pipenv, etc., are useful tools for isolation when developing on a desktop.  When running in Docker there's no need to keep multiple environments separate as Docker is already doing that for you.

Comment: In (Docker) containers, you definitely should use the isolation provided by Python virtual environments! I do not understand why you would do without it, this is a common falsehood.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why not using the usual `python` Docker images? The Python installed in those is perfectly fine. -- Maybe you should show your Dockerfile. -- Or is it actually a container related issue or what?

Comment: I use those containers (based on several different distributions) to both check if the build environment setup works on all relevant platforms and to be able to not pollute the system one is working on. For day-to-day development I use a plain poetry/pipenv environment.

Comment: And also I'm asking out of curiosity - looks like a chicken/egg problem to me I'd like to know how others deal with it. One answer might be they just don't.

Comment: If the goal is to use the Docker containers as development environments, then I do not know too much... I guess: do as you would do on a normal machine. You should not worry too much about having extra unnecessary tools installed in the container. -- If it were for production, it would be different.